# numpy savetxt different cols different format output

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to use `np.savetxt(file,array,fmt='%8.1f')` to save as txt

```
    1958     6.4     1.8     7.7    70.1    41.4    38.5    65.4    25.7    
    1959    27.2    42.5    63.3    86.2   101.5    71.4   114.2   137.9    
    1960    22.9    18.3    28.7   106.5   159.1    50.4     203   121.6     
    1961     4.4    26.9    47.1    67.9    53.6    64.8      95      42     
    1962    20.9    31.2    60.6    38.8    66.2    37.9    67.9    62.3    
    1963    11.9    14.5      59      56    83.1   110.9    77.1    93.5
```

each element take up 8 spaces one by one(no seperation between each one).
First cols year format is `%8d`, and others is `%8.1f`. flush right.
How to do this in `numpy`? or using `pandas`?

Answer (score 0):

```
n = len(df.columns)
fmt = ('{:8.0f}' + '{:8.1f}' * (n - 1)).format

print(df.apply(lambda x: fmt(*x), 1).to_csv(index=None, header=None))

    1958     6.4     1.8     7.7    70.1    41.4    38.5    65.4    25.7
    1959    27.2    42.5    63.3    86.2   101.5    71.4   114.2   137.9
    1960    22.9    18.3    28.7   106.5   159.1    50.4   203.0   121.6
    1961     4.4    26.9    47.1    67.9    53.6    64.8    95.0    42.0
    1962    20.9    31.2    60.6    38.8    66.2    37.9    67.9    62.3
    1963    11.9    14.5    59.0    56.0    83.1   110.9    77.1    93.5
```

Comment: If the year col is index, could fmt apply on it?